# Is there a captcha solver / decoder / autofiller for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, captcha, solver

I want to write a "client" for megaupload.com in Ruby and I wanted to know if there was a captcha solver / decoder / autofiller for Ruby.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unless the CAPTCHA is really lame - [not](http://www.spike.com/video/borat-not-joke/2782157). The idea behind a CAPTCHA is to ensure that a human is running the show.

> A CAPTCHA or Captcha (pronounced
>   /ˈkæptʃə/) is a type of
>   challenge-response test used in
>   computing to ensure that the response
>   is not generated by a computer.

Comment: If you really need a client for Megaupload, it at least can't do everything automatically. Every download request will require that a user initiates it, so that you can show the captcha to the user and have him or her fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service called [Death by Captcha](http://deathbycaptcha.com/user/login), it's paid $1.4 for 1000 solved captchas. You can use with a [this gem](https://github.com/infosimples/deathbycaptcha)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try installing [this gem](https://github.com/alex-rodriguez/easy_captcha_solver) to run a free captcha solver for you in Ruby. Give me feedback to let me know how it works. Thanks. :)